Why does Now in Android have a route layer above the screen layer?
I'm studying Jetpack Compose using the Now in Android project, but I'm not entirely sure what the route layer's role is. My guess is that it's added to manage data, but I'm confused because I see data being managed on the screen as well.
In the ForYouScreen.kt file within the com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.feature.foryou package, I believe moving itemsAvailable, isFeedLoading, and itemsAvailable to a route layer would make the screen code more readable and simplify modifications to the data-related code. What is the purpose of the route layer?
nia
@Composable
internal fun ForYouRoute(
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: ForYouViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val onboardingUiState by viewModel.onboardingUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val feedState by viewModel.feedState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val isSyncing by viewModel.isSyncing.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val deepLinkedUserNewsResource by viewModel.deepLinkedNewsResource.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    ForYouScreen(
        isSyncing = isSyncing,
        onboardingUiState = onboardingUiState,
        feedState = feedState,
        deepLinkedUserNewsResource = deepLinkedUserNewsResource,
        onTopicCheckedChanged = viewModel::updateTopicSelection,
        onDeepLinkOpened = viewModel::onDeepLinkOpened,
        onTopicClick = onTopicClick,
        saveFollowedTopics = viewModel::dismissOnboarding,
        onNewsResourcesCheckedChanged = viewModel::updateNewsResourceSaved,
        onNewsResourceViewed = { viewModel.setNewsResourceViewed(it, true) },
        modifier = modifier,
    )
}

@Composable
internal fun ForYouScreen(
    isSyncing: Boolean,
    onboardingUiState: OnboardingUiState,
    feedState: NewsFeedUiState,
    deepLinkedUserNewsResource: UserNewsResource?,
    onTopicCheckedChanged: (String, Boolean) -> Unit,
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    onDeepLinkOpened: (String) -> Unit,
    saveFollowedTopics: () -> Unit,
    onNewsResourcesCheckedChanged: (String, Boolean) -> Unit,
    onNewsResourceViewed: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val isOnboardingLoading = onboardingUiState is OnboardingUiState.Loading
    val isFeedLoading = feedState is NewsFeedUiState.Loading

    // This code should be called when the UI is ready for use and relates to Time To Full Display.
    ReportDrawnWhen { !isSyncing && !isOnboardingLoading && !isFeedLoading }

    val itemsAvailable = feedItemsSize(feedState, onboardingUiState)

I searched Google, reviewed the entire screen file from the Now in Android project, and checked the official Android documentation, but I still couldn't figure out the purpose of the route layer.

Try no to treat this stuff like it's a science. There's no single "right way" to do things. Sometimes people just do things because it makes sense to them at the time.

Agreed, sometimes you just go with what feels right.

There is no hard rule to do this.
One advantage, though, is to decouple the view model from the Screen. With this the Screen's parameters are only primitives or simple data classes and callbacks. You don't have to bother with properly obtaining the view model (using the right dependency injection framework and maybe specifying the viewmodel owner) and collecting flows and you do not need to bother about navigation.
The Route only contains the setup code so the Screen is truly independent from anything not directly Compose-related. That increases reusability and makes it easier to switch frameworks. You can also create @Previews more easily.
As you already pointed out, the disadvantage is that even simple refactorings like changing parameters are more arduous.

Then, what do you think about using LaunchedEffect to handle initialization logic within a route?

Depends if it's useful or not. Make sure that your LaunchedEffect only initializes Compose UI and no data, since the initialization logic will be repeated on each configuration change (like device rotations). Everything else should be done in the view model.
